# Local behavior of smooth triangulations

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds, triangulations

If $M$ is a smooth $n$- manifold, a smooth triangulation is defined to be a homeomorphism from a simplicial complex $K$ to $M$ whose restriction to each simplex is a smooth embedding. It's a well-known theorem of Whitehead that such triangulations always exist.

Given such a triangulation, I'm wondering if the following is true: For each point $p \in M$, we may find smooth coordinates on a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ such that the intersection of each $k$-simplex with $U$ is contained in a linear $k$-plane in $\mathbb{R}^n$. In other words, the triangulation is smoothly modeled on a linear triangulation of $\mathbb{R}^n$. It's easy to do this individually for each simplex (i.e., find a chart for which the inclusion of that simplex is linear) using the inverse function theorem, but that doesn't address the issue of finding a single such chart for all the simplices simultaneously.

I think I see how to do it using some of the approximation results in Munkres' *Elementary Differential Topology*, but I'm just wondering if this appears in the literature anywhere. I haven't managed to find it stated in that form.

Comment: There's a different proof that such triangulations exist, due to Whitney. I sketch the argument in my lecture notes, see page 1483 of https://www.uni-regensburg.de/Fakultaeten/nat_Fak_I/friedl/papers/2020_friedl-algebraic-topology.pdf       For smooth triangulations that are obtained from construction it is basically clear that your statement holds.

Answer (score 2):

It's one of these standard mistakes on triangulations (found even in some research papers by well-known people). The answer is generically negative,
provided that the combinatorial link of some cell
in $K$ is complicated enough --- here, ``generically'' refers to the simplexwise smooth
embedding. Indeed, the linear representations of quivers come into play.

For a simple counterexample, consider a smooth
triangulation $K$ of any manifold $M$ of dimension $n\ge 3$, and
a codimension-$2$ cell $\alpha$ of $K$ lying in the boundary of at least
four codimension-$1$ cells $\eta_i$ of $K$ ($1\le i\le 4$).
At every point $x\in\alpha$,
the four lines $\tau_x\eta_i/\tau_x\alpha$ have in the $2$-plane $\tau_xM/\tau_x\alpha$
a cross-ratio $c(x)\in R\setminus\{0,1\}$; and the function $c$ on $\alpha$ is generically not constant on any neighborhood of a given point $x_0\in\alpha$. Then, $K$ is not linearizable in any neighborhood of $x_0$.

Comment: A similar example uses just two codimension two simplices. One defines a plane. The other crosses through that plane, from one side of the $\alpha$ to the other. Say, $n=3$, the 1-simplex is the vanishing locus of $x$ and $y$; the linear 2-simplex has vanishing $y$ and positive $x$ and the non-linear 2-simplex has negative $x$ and $y=xz$.

Comment: Right, Ben! It's even simpler.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I guess the better question is: Can an arbitrary triangulation be approximated (after suitable subdivision) by one with the property I described? I think that's the content of approximation by the secant map, as in Chapter 9 of Munkres' "Elementary Differential Topology," but I'm trying to pin down the precise statement.

Comment: I'm afraid that the answer in "no" again. In fact, Ben's obstruction, as well as the one I give, are both open (persistent by C^1-small perturbations) and persistent by subdivisions.